# Polars jemalloc Error 'Unsupported system page size'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-polars

When using polars to create a df on a raspberr pi, I get the following error:

```
<jemalloc>: Unsupported system page size
memory allocation of 8 bytes failed
Aborted
```

The works on my Laptop, and on both machines I have the same page size:

```
getconf PAGE_SIZE
16384
```

Do you have any idea whats the actual issue and how I can solve it?

Comment: Is there a `polars-lts-cpu` package for the raspberry-pi?

Comment: I encounter the same issue when using 'polats-lts-cpu'

Comment: Ah okay. Sounds like something you'd need to ask directly/file a bug for e.g. on Discord / Github. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues?q=Unsupported+system+page+size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rebooting with kernel=kernel8.img in /boot/config.txt changes memory page size from 16kB to 4kB and seems to resolve the issue. getconf PAGESIZE will show the current memory page size.

Answer (score 0):

See list of programs with this issue (including jemalloc) at https://github.com/raspberrypi/bookworm-feedback/issues/107. Also suggests kernel8.img

Comment: Hi user23127710, welcome to SO. While your link may answer the question, link-only answers don't meet the criteria for a good answer on SO. Links can go dead, and review [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) for more info. Thanks